# Dependency not found in Scala

Tags: scala, import, dependencies, sbt

I have a problem related to importing dependencies in Scala build.sbt. I add something like this:

```
name := "DataScala"
version := "0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.paulgoldbaum" %% "scala-influxdb-client" % "0.6.1"
scalaVersion := "2.9"
```

I have a lot of errors

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.paulgoldbaum:scala-influxdb-client_2.9:0.6.1
[error]   not found: C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\local\com.paulgoldbaum\scala-influxdb-client_2.9\0.6.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client_2.9/0.6.1/scala-influxdb-client_2.9-0.6.1.pom
[error] Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9
[error]   not found: C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.9\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9/scala-library-2.9.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.paulgoldbaum:scala-influxdb-client_2.9:0.6.1
[error]   not found: C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\local\com.paulgoldbaum\scala-influxdb-client_2.9\0.6.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client_2.9/0.6.1/scala-influxdb-client_2.9-0.6.1.pom
[error] Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9
[error]   not found: C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.9\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9/scala-library-2.9.pom
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 2020-01-23 21:44:44
[info] shutting down sbt server)
```

Version of the dependency is the newest so I think it is not the case. I have tried to import more libraries like breeze but I could not as well.

Comment: Scala `2.9` is probably older than myself. I would suggest trying with a newer version, like `2.11.12` or `2.12.10` or `2.13.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 2.9? I am not sure such a version ever existed. Usually Scala version numbers are using three components.

Looking at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client this library exists for 2.10.x, 2.11.x or 2.12.x.

Use 2.12.10 for the `scalaVersion`.

Comment: 2.9.0 was released at May 2011 - I'm betting on some super-legacy codebase (wow) or really outdated tutorial/book.